# How could Weyoun be present during the signing of the peace treaty?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

I was quite surprised to find out that Weyoun was present during the signing of the peace treaty between the Dominion and the Federation.

It was clearly explained earlier in the same or previous episode that

> Dominion cloning facilities are not operational and thus the existing Weyoun clone was the last one "available" to serve the Female Changeling.

Some time after this explanation we learned that

> this last clone was shot during the headquarters take-over.

I can hardly belive that Federation allowed the Dominion/Cardassia to put cloning facilities back into full operation *before* signing a peace treaty. Which leads us to the conlusion that there was no clone left to  serve as the Female Changeling’s advisor.

For me this is a quite obvious hole in script. Can anyone confirm this? Or, on the contrary, maybe there is an explanation for how Weyoun could be present during the signing of the peace treaty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The two Vorta present were not Weyoun clones. They were simply *other Vorta*, in this particular case played by [Mark Major](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mark_Major) and [Keith Rayve](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Keith_Rayve)

Per the [script.](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/575.txt)

> The Female Shape-shifter, TWO VORTA and THREE JEM'HADAR FIRSTS, are
>   seated at the table signing the official surrender documents. In front
>   of them stand, Sisko, Ross, Martok and a Romulan dignitary. Among the
>   WITNESSES filling the room, are Kira, Odo, Worf, Bashir, O'Brien, Ezri
>   and **various other STARFLEET OFFICERS, VORTA and JEM'HADAR.**
>
> Once the Female Shape-shifter completes the signing of the surrender
>   documents, she stands and hands them to Admiral Ross.

[image]